# How can I mount a Dino head to a wall?

Tags: connections

[image]I would like to mount the head of the Dino Triceratops, Item No: [30460](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=30460), onto a brick/connector so it would be possible to fix it to a wall or over a door entrance. Any ideas on that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't have this particular piece but my advice for most 'non-standard' connections such as these is to use a part that is flexible enough to fit the gap.

The ['Technic, Axle Connector Double Flexible'](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=45590#T=C) piece under compression can make a snug enough fit to mount a sharks head.

In this example, you can use two [Technic Axle-Pin](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=43093#T=C) attached to another two [Technic 1X1](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=6541#T=C) bricks.

[image]

[image]

[image]

If you turn the rubber brick 90 degrees on it's side and place two of them together you might be able to attach something that isn't as wide.

Comment: very clever. not sure if the dino head connector is wide enough for this exact solution. I have to try. But the idea is inspiring to think out of the box, thanx.

Comment: If you turn the rubber brick 90 degrees on it's side and place two of them together you might be able to attach something that isn't as wide.

Answer (score 1):

- **PROJECT: Dinosaur mount.**  [image]

  [image]
- **Black plaque construction and cradle.**
    [image]

  [image]

  [image]

  [image]
- **Mounting plaque to a wall.**
     [image]

  [image]

  [image]

  [image]

  [image]
- Reconstructed *Ambo100's* nice entry, which works beautifully for
  *Mr. Shark*, but the width is too sore for *Lady Dinosaur*.

  [image]

  [image]

Answer (score 0):

The horn piece I have from an old castle set, and you can grab it with minifigure hands. I can't think of a visually appealing way to mount it by the horn,but it is still an option.

Comment: visually interesting idea. I think in this case the minifig concept would not fit to the requirement of the project but I will keep it in mind.